# Error when installing mod_perl2

Tags: apache, perl, centos, mod-perl2

I am trying to install mod_perl2 with below configuration: 
 **OS:** CentOS release 5.5 (Final) 
**Uname -a result:** x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
 **Perl version:** v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
**apache version:** Apache/2.2.3 
 I have downloaded mod_perl2 from [Cpan site](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/mod_perl-2.0.10.tar.gz)

 when I try to run the "perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/usr/local/httpd/bin/apxs" it gives below output:

> Subroutine set_version redefined at ./Makefile.PL line 137.
>   [   info] generating script t/TEST
>   [   info] generating script ./t/cgi-bin/cookies.pl
>   [   info] generating script ./t/cgi-bin/next_available_port.pl
>   Checking for Cwd...ok
>   Checking for File::Spec...ok
>   [   info] generating script t/TEST
>   Generating a Unix-style Makefile
>   Writing Makefile for mod_perl2
>   [warning] mod_perl dso library will be built as mod_perl.so
>   [warning] You'll need to add the following to httpd.conf:
>   [warning]
>   [warning]   LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
>   [warning]
>   [warning] depending on your build, mod_perl might not live in
>   [warning] the modules/ directory.
>   
>   [warning] Check the results of
>   [warning]
>   [warning]   $ /usr/local/httpd/bin/apxs -q LIBEXECDIR
>   [warning]
>   [warning] and adjust the LoadModule directive accordingly.

> After "make" command runs below error occurs: 
>  
>   modperl_env.c: In function ‘modperl_env_magic_local_all’:
>   modperl_env.c:544: error: ‘MGf_LOCAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   modperl_env.c:544: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   modperl_env.c:544: error: for each function it appears in.)
>   modperl_env.c: At top level:
>   modperl_env.c:642: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
>   modperl_env.c:642: warning: (near initialization for ‘MP_vtbl_env’)
>   modperl_env.c: In function ‘modperl_env_init’:
>   modperl_env.c:661: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘Perl_mg_find’ discards 
> qualifiers from pointer target type
>   modperl_env.c:673: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mg_free_type’
>   modperl_env.c:678: error: ‘MGf_LOCAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   modperl_env.c: In function ‘modperl_env_unload’:
>   modperl_env.c:690: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘Perl_mg_find’ discards 
> qualifiers from pointer target type
>   make[1](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/mod_perl-2.0.10.tar.gz): *** [modperl_env.lo] Error 1
>
>   make[1](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/mod_perl-2.0.10.tar.gz): Leaving directory `/opt/mod_perl-2.0.10/src/modules/perl'
>
>   make: *** [modperl_lib] Error 2

any help is appriciated, if i have asked somthing wrong please guide further (no down votes please :) )

Comment: Don't post screenshots of logs. Copy and paste the actual text.

Comment: @SinanÜnür removed images

Comment: My guess is your Apache libraries are an incompatible version.

Answer (score 2):

This constant as been introduced in perl 5.9.3, and mod_perl use it from 2.0.10.

http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Variable-Magic-0.62/lib/Variable/Magic.pm#MGf_LOCAL
https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/a5063e7cd8fef802efd25ffe9df2c3748f4254f6
https://github.com/apache/mod_perl/commit/82827132efd3c2e25cc413c85af61bb63375da6e
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html

to overcome this you must modify mod_perl to use this constant conditionaly of the perl version:

```
diff -ruw mod_perl-2.0.11/src/modules/perl/modperl_env.c mod_perl-2.0.11.patched/src/modules/perl/modperl_env.c
--- mod_perl-2.0.11/src/modules/perl/modperl_env.c      2017-12-06 11:08:55.000000000 -0500
+++ mod_perl-2.0.11.patched/src/modules/perl/modperl_env.c      2018-03-27 15:02:14.174790000 -0400
@@ -541,7 +541,9 @@
     nmg = sv_magicext(nsv, mg->mg_obj, mg->mg_type, &MP_vtbl_env, (char*)NULL, 0);
     nmg->mg_ptr = mg->mg_ptr;
     nmg->mg_flags |= MGf_COPY;
+#if MP_PERL_VERSION_AT_LEAST(5, 9, 3)
     nmg->mg_flags |= MGf_LOCAL;
+#endif

     return 1;
 }
@@ -679,7 +681,9 @@
     /* Add our version instead */
     mg = sv_magicext((SV*)ENVHV, (SV*)NULL, PERL_MAGIC_env, &MP_vtbl_env, (char*)NULL, 0);
     mg->mg_flags |= MGf_COPY;
+#if MP_PERL_VERSION_AT_LEAST(5, 9, 3)
     mg->mg_flags |= MGf_LOCAL;
+#endif
 }

 void modperl_env_unload(pTHX)
```

Answer (score 1):

A modified/enhanced version of Mathieu Carbonneaux's patch above was committed to the mod_perl SVN repository on October 8th, 2019:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1868115

With this patch, mod_perl 2.0.11 will compile and install using Perl <= 5.8.8.

(Sorry, I don't have the reputation to comment, only answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to build your own version of mod_perl? Centos has a pre-built version of mod_perl which will work with the pre-built version of Perl that is already installed.

```
$ sudo yum install mod_perl
```

(Of course, this won't help if you're not using the system Perl)

Comment: Something must be wrong with your `yum` configuration. Centos definitely has an RPM for mod_perl. See http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/

Comment: RPM installation worked successfully but, apache is not able to find mod_perl.so

Comment: Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40745426/edit) with details of the current situation

Comment: sorry no success... with Rpm mod_perl gets installed but apache is unable to find the **mod_perl.so**, from source code or CPAN shell above errors are remain same :(

Comment: Is your Apache from an rpm?

Comment: Why not try again - this time installing everything from RPMs.

Answer (score 0):

dont know how but mod_perl-2.0.6 has got installed successfully. had no success with the mod_perl-2.0.10 :(